# Customize the cross-reference appearance when referring not-exist labels

Tags: cleveref

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
see \cref{fig-not-exist}
\end{document}
```

The reference appears as a double question mark by default.

I want to show the label `fig-not-exist` itself instead.

Answer (score 2):

Patching the command to replace `??` with the argument of the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@setcref}%
{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}}
{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries #2}}
{}
{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
see \cref{fig-not-exist, fig-not-exist2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems not work when ref more than one labels `\cref{fig-not-exist, fig-not-exist2}`.

Comment: @jiewuza Seems to work for me with more than one label.

Comment: Well, it shows `fig-not-exist2fig-not-exist`. Good, but not perfect. The order changes and no separator.